# How to give path for images with spring mvc maven?

Tags: spring-mvc

[image]

I am using maven dependency jars for bootstrap and jquery. I am given  following code in spring-servlet.xml.

```
mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**" location="/webjars/"  
    cache-period="31556926"
```

now  i want to give images paths in jsp page.images available in resources folder.How to give path for images?

Comment: I think you should put the `img` folder under the `webapp` folder tree. You can also try to set the location to `"img/"` - might work, not sure.

Comment: thanks for reply.img error icon showing.i added img under webapps/WEB-INF/img/logo.png. In jsp <img src=WEB-INF/img/logo.png .